# Can this sheetrock be repaired or does it need to be replaced?

Tags: repair, drywall

[image]

Removed formica backsplash made a huge mess. Can it be repaired, and if so, how?

Comment: That's an awfully small picture, and it's awkwardly rotated 90 degrees. Can you post a better one?

Comment: Need a better picture.  In general drywall is very malleable and patchable.

Comment: It can be repaired, but it'll take some effort for it to look right. It's probably better to replace. Do you intend to leave the sheetrock exposed? What is your plan for a backsplash? This is behind your range, right?

Comment: Are you going to add another backsplash?

Answer (score 2):

Most anything can be repaired with enough time, money, materials and skill.

Sheetrock, however, is one of the cheapest building materials we use, so when it comes to repairing wall and ceiling surfaces, typically the cheapest/easiest solution is to just re-sheetrock.